# Which tools are most commonly used to auto-encrypt backups for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, backup, encryption

I am looking to automate the encryption of my backups, and SQL Server 2005 does not appear to include built in functionality to do the work. Similar to the question here - [Is it possible to configure SQL Server 2005 to auto-compress backups?](https://serverfault.com/questions/72689/is-it-possible-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-auto-compress-backups) - I am looking for a list of commonly used software to do the job

Comment: You pretty much got that list in mrdenny's answer to your other question.

Comment: Your options are pay for product like SQL Backup, or your own scripts using utilities like 7zip, gpg. Choose!

Answer (score 1):

I have used SQL Backup from Red Gate for more than 2 years now and its awesome. It encrypts, compresses, recovers from network drop-outs and gives you object level restores from native backup files. They do a free 14 day trial, here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Backup/index.htm

Hope you give it a go, you wont be disappointed.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Not with SQL 2005.

You might want to read over this topic: [Is it possible to configure SQL Server 2005 to auto-compress backups?](https://serverfault.com/questions/72689/is-it-possible-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-auto-compress-backups)

A lot of those answers will apply to this one as well as compress & encrypt tend to go hand-in-hand.

Comment: Yes, I separated this issue out from that question, since I'm looking for a separate answer. I'll edit my question to make it clearer

Comment: Silly me! I didn't notice you were author of both.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL 2005 you can't encrypt backups, but you can encrypt them using third party tools.

Encryption and compression don't go hand-in-hand. Encrypted files are hard to compress, so if space is a concern, you might want to compress in stead of encrypt files and protect those compressed files with a password.

Comment: The second paragraph was apprently in response to my answer. It might've made more sense to put it as a comment on said answer...  Also, please notice the word "tend" in my answer -- but I don't currently know anyone compressing without encrypting or vice-versa